# Need to loop through new leads in a flow, displaying in a screen

Tags: flow, loop

I need to create a Flow that allows me to load all new leads to loop through with a screen.  I have this problem solved as far as identifying the leads to load, and the loop is created as well.  My question is in regards to placing a screen inside a Flow loop and allowing the display and update of the lead fields.  My present loop & screen do in fact loop through the records, but do not allow the display of each lead in the screen, the screen displays the first lead and does not update.  It also seems to get caught in an endless loop in doing so.  I have included a screen shot of my Flow below.  Thanks in advance for your help!

[image: Flow diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could the issue be that you are not assigning your loop Sobject variable into your loop assignment collection variable that you update after the loop exits?

The last Fast Update "Save updated leads" what collection variable are you using here?  If it is the same one from your initial fast lookup, then this is why it is not working (or at least not updating.)

Try adding another assignment after the Update Leads assignment.  This assignment should add to Loop sobject variable to a new collection variable.  Then change the fast update to update the new collection variable.